# Tools to display React-Native components on web

Tags: reactjs, react-native, documentation-generation, native-base

I have a react-native project that's built using **Metro** and **Native Base** and I'm trying normalize the UI by extracting a styleguide out of it. I would like it to be documented so I can share it and work along with the designers.

Cheers!

I already tried **Storybook**, **Docz** and **React-Styleguidist**.

**React-Styleguidist**: This one I liked the fact that it could be placed outside the project.

**Docz**: seems to be the easiest but it seems to have a problem with Native-Base

**Storybook**: Seems to require the you have an emulator running to display any documentation.

Anyway, I couldn't make any of them work. So if you guys have some suggestions regarding these or other tools, I'd be glad to hear them.

The best would be to have a browser based that lifts the documentation from outside the repo and parses something that's browsable and I can share with the designers.

Comment: Did you find a good solution for this?

Comment: Found a few but couldn't make them work. I liked Docz, it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use react-native-web package that compiles native components to HTML.
https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web

Comment: I will review this to see if it works for me. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Please add a comment if that's useful.